# Finding the area enclosed by three curves

Tags: integration, area

I need to find the area that is enclosed between three curves. I was trying to look for the smartest solution visually, but haven't gotten anywhere.

Curves:
$$y_1= 2x^2$$
$$y_2 = x^2$$
$$y_3 = \frac{1}{x}$$

Please help

Comment: Did you try looking at a graph of all the functions? Try to observe that, and figure definite integrals with the correct limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

\begin{align}
\int_0^{1/\sqrt[3]2} f_1(x)&-f_2(x)\, dx
+
\int_{1/\sqrt[3]2}^1 f_3(x)-f_2(x)\, dx
\\
&=
\int_0^{1/\sqrt[3]2} x^2\, dx
+
\int_{1/\sqrt[3]2}^1 \frac1x-x^2\, dx
\\
&=
\tfrac13x^3\Big|_0^{1/\sqrt[3]2}
+
(\ln(x)-\tfrac13x^3)
\Big|_{1/\sqrt[3]2}^1
\\
&=\tfrac13\ln2
\approx 0.2310 
,
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

One way to calculate the mentioned area is using double integrals. Strictly speaking, **Change of variables theorem** works perfect here. The general idea in this theorem is to transform the area to a well-known one, which here seems to be a rectangle, and then apply iteration method. So let the dedicated area be $D$. Then using change of variables theorem for double integrals we have:
$$\text{area of $D$} = \iint\limits_D dx dy = \iint\limits_{D'} \left\lvert \dfrac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right\rvert dudv.$$
where $u = \dfrac{y}{x^2}$ and $v = xy$. Note that with new variables, $D$ is transformed to $D'$ which is a rectangle in $\text{$uv$-plane}$ bounded by lines $u=1, u=2$ and $v=1, v=0$. Also note that group of curves $xy = k$ for $0 < k \leq 1$ cover the area of $D$ and each point in $D$ belongs to exactly one of these curves (i.e. the transformation is both surjective and bijective). Having said these and the inverse function theorem which states that $$\left\lvert \dfrac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right\rvert = \dfrac{1}{\left\lvert \dfrac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\right\rvert},$$
we have:
$$\left\lvert \dfrac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}\right\rvert = \dfrac{3y}{x^2} = 3u \Longrightarrow \left\lvert \dfrac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right\rvert = \dfrac{1}{3u}.$$
Therfore:
$$\iint\limits_{D'} \left\lvert \dfrac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right\rvert dudv = \iint\limits_{D'} \dfrac{1}{3u}dudv = \frac{1}{3} \int_0^1 dv \int_1^2 \dfrac{du}{u} = \frac{1}{3} \times 1 \times (\ln2 - \ln 1) = \frac{1}{3} \ln 2.$$
Further reading at the section 14.4 of *Calculus, a complete course* by *R. A. Adams*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to solve this visually, but we can solve it with integrals.

First, we need to find where the different equations intersect each other.

1. $y_1=y_2\rightarrow2x^2=x^2\rightarrow x^2=0\rightarrow x=0$
2. $y_1=y_3\rightarrow2x^2=\frac{1}{x}\rightarrow x^3=\frac{1}{2}\rightarrow x=\frac{1}{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{2}}$
3. $y_2=y_3\rightarrow x^2=\frac{1}{x}\rightarrow x^3=1\rightarrow x=1$

The area enclosed by the three curves is $\int_0^\frac{1}{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{2}}y_1-y_2dx+\int_\frac{1}{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{2}}^1y_3-y_2dx=\int_0^\frac{1}{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{2}}(2x^2-x^2)dx+\int_\frac{1}{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{2}}^1(\frac{1}{x}-x^2)dx=\int_0^\frac{1}{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{2}}x^2dx+\int_\frac{1}{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{2}}^1\frac{1}{x}dx-\int_\frac{1}{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{2}}^1x^2dx=\int_0^\frac{1}{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{2}}x^2dx+\int_\frac{1}{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{2}}^1\frac{1}{x}dx-\int_\frac{1}{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{2}}^1x^2dx=\frac{1}{6}+\ln(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}3]{2}}})-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{3}\ln(2)$

Comment: Try to give hints first rather than providing complete solution. Also, ask OP for their attempt or what more they know about the context. [Read this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/homework-questions-avoiding-giving-a-complete-solution).

Answer (score 0):

After visual observation, the integral is equivalent to

$$\int_0^1\min\left(x^2,\dfrac1x-x^2\right)\,dx$$ which you decompose as

$$\int_0^a x^2\,dx+\int_a^1\left(\dfrac1x-x^2\right)\,dx=\frac{a^3}3-\log a-\frac{1-a^3}3.$$ $a$ is the abscissa of the meeting point of the two functions.